# Typescript: Cannot find name argument in anonymous function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This code snippet gives TS error:
`Cannot find name c`.

I want to call the anonymous function `b` but cannot access the argument `c` of the anonymous function.

```
function fn(a: number, b: (c: number) => void) {
  b(c);
}
```

Comment: c would be accessible only inside function b, it would be better if you can give a bit more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood the params passed. The section `(c: number) => void` is a type, it does not mean c is a individual parameter. You can rewrite this as.

```js
function fn(a, b) {
  b(c);
}
const c = 1234;
function test(cParam) {
  console.log(cParam);
}
fn(1, test.bind(c));
```

So here, `b` is the function `test` which takes one input parameter. We can use `.bind(c)` to let javascript know that when the `b` variable inside function `fn` executes, we should take the first paramter as `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you call `fn`, you would not pass a function with its argument. You would call it with a reference to the other function. For example:

`fn(21, myOtherFunction)`

Therefore, something like this works:

```
const fn = (a: number, b: (c: number) => void) => {
  b(a);
}
```

Just pass what you thought of as `c` as your first argument instead.